# Trying to fix a cast error

Tags: android

I am currently working on a project were i am trying to create a registration page. Below is the code for my two activities:

My Start activity code is as follows:

```
package com.example.profmox.k_mart;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Start extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button regButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        regButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.register);
        regButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent reg_intent = new Intent(Start.this,Register.class);
                startActivity(reg_intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and my Register class code:

```
package com.example.profmox.k_mart;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextInputLayout regName,regEmail,regPassword;
    private Button regCreate;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        regName = (TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.reg_displayName);
        regEmail = (TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
        regPassword = (TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
        regCreate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.reg_create);

        regCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String display_name = regName.getEditText().getText().toString();
                String email = regEmail.getEditText().getText().toString();
                String password = regPassword.getEditText().getText().toString();

                registerUser(display_name,email,password);
            }
        });
    }

    private void registerUser(String display_name, String email, String password) {
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            startActivity(new Intent(Register.this, MainActivity.class));
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

layout code for my start activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Start">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Welcome to K-Mart"
        android:textSize="24dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/register"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="126dp"
        android:text="@string/need_a_new_account" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

layout code for my register activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Register">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_displayName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/display_name" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/reg_email"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/email" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/reg_password"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/reg_email">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/password" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reg_create"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/create_account"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/reg_password" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

but every time i click on the button in my start activity it crushes the app and sends out the following error message:

```
 08-21 15:55:34.884 9689-9689/com.example.profmox.k_mart E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.profmox.k_mart, PID: 9689
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.profmox.k_mart/com.example.profmox.k_mart.Register}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
        at com.example.profmox.k_mart.Register.onCreate(Register.java:31)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

how can i resolve this issue because i cannot find anywhere in my code where it is showing errors.

Comment: Can You send Your layout xml?

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText`

Comment: Clean/rebuild your project.

Comment: Open XML file check there is any let EditText over there

Comment: You can't cast an apple to a banana...

Comment: Did you clean/rebuild? Your stack trace should've changed, if that is indeed the current, correct layout.

Comment: i have cleaned and rebuilt the  project and have even changed the casting but it still crashes on button click in the start activity

Comment: Yes, with the posted code, it should still crash, but it would be a different Exception message. You're not casting to `EditText` anywhere in that code, so your build was out-of-date.  `reg_email` and `reg_password` are `TextInputLayout`s, but `reg_displayName` is a `TextInputEditText`. You've got them a little mixed up between the layout and the code.

Comment: That's more like it, a current build. Now just go through your layout carefully and make sure the IDs correspond to what you've got in the code. You're going to have to adjust at least one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your register activity's layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout1"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_displayName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="string/display_name" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout1">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="string/email" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout3"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout2">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="string/password" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reg_create"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="string/create_account"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout3" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

change:

```
private TextInputEditText regName,regEmail,regPassword;

regName = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_displayName);
regEmail = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
regPassword = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
```

and

```
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String display_name = regName.getText().toString();
        String email = regEmail.getText().toString();
        String password = regPassword.getText().toString();

        registerUser(display_name,email,password);
    }
```

Comment: even after changing them to `TextInputEditText` i have to change `String display_name = regName.getEditText().getText().toString();` to `String display_name = regName.getText().toString();` but still it crushes with that change

Comment: Remove getEditText()

Comment: To the downvoter: are you shy? why don't you explain?

Comment: @ProvidenceMoyo change this private TextInputLayout regName,regEmail,regPassword; to private TextInputEditText regName,regEmail,regPassword;

Comment: i have made that change but still when i run the app after all those changes it still crushes before it even opens the Register activity.

Comment: @ProvidenceMoyo did you change the declaration to TextInputEditText ?

Comment: yes i have changed the declaration to `TextInputEditText`

Comment: And the log is the same? cast problem?

Comment: @ProvidenceMoyo I fixed your layout because you had mixed the ids of TextInputLayouts and TextInputEditTexts

Comment: @ProvidenceMoyo It took me some time to dig into your layout

Answer (score 0):

Pass id of `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout instead of android.support.design.widget.EditTextLayout`

While casting view

Comment: where exactly should i do that?

Comment: On Register Class in onCreate() instantiate view ex:  regPassword = (TextInputLayout)findViewById();

Answer (score 0):

CHange your TextInputLayout to TextInputEditText

```
    private TextInputEditText regName,regEmail,regPassword;

    regName = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_displayName);
    regEmail = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
    regPassword = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
```

Also,

```
regCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String display_name = regName.getText().toString();
                String email = regEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = regPassword.getText().toString();
                registerUser(display_name,email,password);
            }
        });
```

Comment: even after these changes, the app still crashes as soon as i click on the button in the start activity